# ASP.NET 2.0 Gridview bit checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

I have a column in my database that is a bit. The column gets into my gridview from a stored proc and its setting the column in the gridview to a checkbox, and thats ok. For all the other columns I am using

```
    GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).SelectedRow;
    textbox.Text = row.Cells[x].Text.ToString();
```

I have used this to set all the text boxes in my form from the database. But i am trying to find the code to access the checkbox in the gridview. I have tried

```
    row.cells[bitColumn].Text.ToString
```

But that does not return a 1 or 0.

So my question is this when you have a checkbox in a gridview how do you access it? So that I could set a checkbox in my form based on this bit.

Comment: Because I am in a time crunch I went into my database and used a case statment and cast the result as a varchar forcing the gridview to bring in the column as text which i can access as i have been with the other columns. Though in the interest of reference. I will keep responding to this question to find the right way to do what i was trying to accomplish for those that may come after me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like accessing columns by indexing them by number - you never know when they will change.  Instead try to access them by name:

`CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("chkSelector");`

Where `chkSelector` is an ASP.net checkbox control.
Then you can check if `cb.Checked`.  This will return a boolean as true / false you can then map that to your bit.  If `cb.Checked` is `true` assign the value 1 else assign the value 0.

Comment: Does this work if i am autogenerating the columns. The checkbox column in the gridview is getting generated at runtime, so I am not sure how to access it.

Comment: Hi Michael, in this case just use your index if you would like.  But assign it to a checkbox control `Checkbox cb = (Checkbox)row.Cells[x];` and check if `cb.Checked` is true.

Comment: gotcha Thank you again for the quick repsonse and the information.